# Solaris: determine if login shell (su -) or not

Tags: solaris, ksh

What's the best way to determine from a ksh script if the current shell is a login shell (`su - user`) or not (`su user`).

I'm toying with:

```
user=$(/usr/xpg4/bin/id -un)
login=$(grep $HOME /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1 | head -1)
if [ "$login" == "$user" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

or perhaps instead using the `$MAIL` variable based on a comment in the [su man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5166/su-1m.html) that only `su -` sets MAIL:

```
user=$(/usr/xpg4/bin/id -un)
login=${MAIL##*/}
if [ "$login" == "$user" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

but neither seems strictly airtight. Is there a best-practice approach?

Answer (score 1):

```
case "$0" in
    -*) echo "I'm a login shell";;
esac
```

Comment: Nice! The only problem is that $0 will be the script name inside a script. Is there a way to examine shell flags, perhaps?

Comment: @David Citron: A script is never going to be the login shell itself, so it's not going to be able to check itself - it would have to check its parent (or parent's parent, etc), and I'm not sure how it would do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one best practice.  Anything based on recognizing variables is unreliable, and even walking up your process hierarchy requires making inferences because **su** executes **login** without forking, leaving no trace what its arguments were.

The better choice is to test directly for the settings you need.  Usually, what I'm interested in when looking for login shells is that the profile was read.  So, if you have free reign to modify your profile, set an indicator variable:

```
echo "export parsed_profile=true" >> ~/.profile
```

And then check that directly.  Another option would be to verify you own your $HOME:

```
if /bin/test \! -O "$HOME"; then
    echo HOME is not set or set incorrectly.
fi
```

Or just directly source your profile from inside your script.

Answer (score 0):

It may be, that your question is simpler than I'm making it; you might simply be asking how to tell if the user *logged in as root or used su to switch to them* in which case, a combination of the answers I've given would be appropriate.

Normally, a login shell is differentiated from a non-login-shell by whether various scripts got run. The reason many users start a non-login-shell is because it is a subshell of some program, or (as you note) because they use `su` to switch users. *Those* users will have `$LOGNAME` not equal to `$USER`

Unless, of course, they switch back. To detect those users, consider the following perl script:

```
open(P,"ps -ef|");while(<P>){m#^(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)#;$u{$2}=$1;$t{$2}=$3;}
$p=$$;while($t{$p}){$g{$u{$p}}=1;$p=$t{$p};}delete$g{root};$g{$u{$$}}=1;
print keys(%g),"\n";
```

If you want to restrict it to using `su -` you can use:

```
open(P,"ps -ef|");while(<P>){m#^(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+).*su - #;$u{$2}=$1;$t{$2}=$3;}
$p=$$;while($t{$p}){$g{$u{$p}}=1;$p=$t{$p};}delete$g{root};$g{$u{$$}}=1;
print keys(%g),"\n";
```

If you want to *really* see login shells, note that login shells are started with `argv[0]` set with a leading dash, so you can use:

```
open(P,"ps -eo user,pid,ppid,comm|");while(<P>){m#^(\S+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+) -#;
  $u{$2}=$1;$t{$2}=$3;}
$p=$$;while($t{$p}){$g{$u{$p}}=1;$p=$t{$p};}delete$g{root};$g{$u{$$}}=1;
print keys(%g),"\n";
```

but you'll miss out on the situation where someone ran `ksh --login`.

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris, root home directory is '/' by default, not '/root'. Some of the previous suggestions are thus unreliable.

Answer (score -1):

This wouldn't be definitive, but should work most of the time

if[$HOME == "/root"] ...

Comment: Well, my `grep $HOME /etc/passwd` option above kinda covers this in a more flexible way...no?